# How to replace one word in URL

Tags: android, json, url

In my URL i want to replace "{chamber}" with "house"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static String url ="http://10.11.32.199/congressionaldirectory/services/getbillsdetailsbychamber?chamber={chamber}&app_code=125143649";

String jsonStr;
TextView tv;

private static final String TAG_CHAMBER = "chamber";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    new GetContacts().execute(url);
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI u;
            try {
                u = new URI(params[0]);
                HttpPost HG=new HttpPost(u);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> al=new ArrayList<NameValuePair();
            al.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_CHAMBER,"house"));
            HG.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(al));
            HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(HG);


            jsonStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());   

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv.setText(jsonStr);}}}
```

if i pass this url directly (http://10.11.32.199/congressionaldirectory/services/getbillsdetailsbychamber?chamber=house&app_code=125143649) its working fine 
pls help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 private public String url ="http://10.11.32.199/congressionaldirectory/services/getbillsdetailsbychamber?chamber={chamber}&app_code=125143649";

 url=url.replace("{chamber}","house");
```

You just need to use string replace function, since it is static and private so it would work smoothly.

Comment: Is this possible to send that "house" to URL  using JSON .

Answer (score 2):

You can use string.replace:

```
private static String url ="http://10.11.32.199/congressionaldirectory/services/getbillsdetailsbychamber?chamber={chamber}&app_code=125143649";

String modified_url = url.replace("{chamber}","house");
```

Comment: why to use another string when we can use the same one :).